# How to redirect all routes from a sub-domain to a path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, devise, rails-routing

I have an application, where requests can come from domain or subdomain. For example:

`admin.example.com` is redirecting to `example.com/admin`. I have achieved this via nginx configuration. But the problem is, for every environment/dev machine, we need to setup nginx.conf. I'd like to do at rails route level.

i.e. all request received from `admin.example.com` should be redirected to `example.com/admin` via rails routing. Also, I need to ensure that `devise` authentication doesn't break.

a snippet of routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index' # Domain request

  devise_for :admins, controllers: {
                        sessions: 'admin/sessions',
                        registrations: 'admin/registrations',
                        passwords: 'admin/passwords',
                        invitations: 'admin/invitations'
                    }
  namespace :admin do
    devise_scope :admin do
      root 'dashboards#show'
      get '/contact-us' => '/home#contact_us'

      resource :dashboard
      resources :users, :only => [:index, :create, :update]
      resources :admins, :customers
      concerns :notifiable
..
..
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to wrap all routes inside of a constraint-block in combination with a "catch-all"-route:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  constraints subdomain: 'www' do
    # ... all routes routes ...
  end
  match '*path' => 'your_controller#your_action', via: :all
end
```

Then, inside of your controller, you'll have access to `request.subdomain`, `request.domain`, `request.path`, etc. and you can construct your redirect to suit your needs.